# How to share an object to multiple users using parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I would like to create an object that I can share with other users. To be more precise, the object would be an account and each user could be able to add expense to it. I'm not really sure how to do it.

Should I use the relations available in parse.com?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but you may find much of the information you need in the documentation:

https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide

This explains how you can relate objects in different ways.

Given that you might want to let a single user have multiple accounts, a column of type `Array<Account>` might work. From the sounds of it you will probably have a `Transaction` or `Expense` class too that is linked to each `Account`.

Once you have that done you should start thinking about security:

https://parse.com/docs/data#security

You will probably want to lock your `Account` object down using an "ACL" (access control list), which lets you set who has what permissions on that row.

Comment: I'm wondering wether I should better bind users to an account or an account to users. What do you think ?

Comment: That will depend mostly on how you intend to query your data, you can even do both.